# Max-height not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery auto-complete search bar. But the max-height of the results is not working and I can't understand why. I want the result to be of some maximum height, followed by a scroll if needed.

```css
.frmSearch {
    margin: 2px 0px;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:7000;
}
#country-list {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:300px;
}
#country-list li {
    padding: 10px;
    background:#FAFAFA;
    border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#country-list li:hover {
    background:#F0F0F0;
}
#search-box {
    padding: 10px;
    border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
    width:300px;
}
#suggesstion-box {
    overflow:scroll;
    max-height:300px;
    position:absolute;
}
#button3 {
    //padding: 2px;
    margin-left:2px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    //font-size: 14px;
    //background:#F0F0F0;
    //color:#303030;
    //border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    //border-radius: 4px;
    vertical-align: -24px;
}
#button3:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
}
#button3:active {
    border: 2px solid #484848;
    cursor:pointer;
    //background:#D0D0D0;
    //padding:1px;
    //font-size:15px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "readCountry.php",
            data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif)   no-repeat 165px");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
            }
        });
    });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="frmSearch">
    <form action="search_result1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" autocomplete="off" name="search" placeholder="Country Name" /> 
        <input type="image" name="submit" value="submit" src="images/searchb1.png" id="button3"/>
    <div>
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Sorry it's hard to tell what's going on. Could you create a Snippet instead of showing all this code, please? Also it would be nice if the src's for the  images were the full addresses: again just to help show us what is going on.

Comment: @jaunt Here's the live box:
http://tutorsvilla.com/join_us1.php

Comment: It seems to me that the max-height is working. Also if you only want the scroll as needed simply set it to auto instead. That way you don't get a greyed out scroll bar when it isn't required.

Comment: @jaunt Thanks for the help. The max-height is working now. But even after setting the scroll to auto, the weird scroll bar pops out.

Comment: It pops out because you're applying those properties to the div and not the ul tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML above is come from the live site, then you need to fix that.

```
<div class="frmSearch">
    <form action="search_result1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" autocomplete="off" name="search" placeholder="Country Name" /> 
        <input type="image" name="submit" value="submit" src="images/searchb1.png" id="button3"/>
    <div>
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
    </form>
```

`<div class"frmSearch">` is not closed, and you have one open `<div>` before `<div id="suggestion-box"></div>`.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7m9y40k/)

Btw, I check your live site but the max-height is working. I tried to set the `max-height` to `100px` and type `a` in the search input. And the result scroll is active.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the problem was with that div. Is there a way to hide the absurd scrollbar though. I've tried setting the scroll to auto.

Comment: Sure :) Btw what you mean? I'm not pretty clear hehe